# Set widget to TreeItem on gwt

Tags: java, gwt, widget

I have to implements a tree on gwt. I'm implementing an object that extends Widget to set it on a TreeItem.

The problem is that if I set on a TreeItem this object (that have only Strings and Integers fields) I can't see anymore the tree.

Where is the problem? I can't see it.

```
private Tree frontEndTree;

private void buildTree(HashMap<Long, Categoria> categoriaMap) {
    for(Categoria categoria : categoriaMap.values()) {

        if(categoria.getLevel() != 1) continue;

        TreeItem firstLevel = //this.frontEndTree.addTextItem(categoria.getDescription());
        this.frontEndTree.addTextItem(categoria.getDescription());
        ItemTree itemTree = new ItemTree(categoria);
        firstLevel.setWidget((Widget)itemTree);
        this.visitaAlbero(firstLevel, categoria.getDescendants());
    }
} 
private void visitaAlbero(TreeItem parentItem, ArrayList<Categoria> categorie) {
    if(categorie == null) return;
    if(categorie.isEmpty()) return;

    TreeItem node = null;
    for(Categoria item : categorie) {
        if(node == null) {
            node = parentItem.addTextItem(item.getDescription());
            node.setWidget(new ItemTree(item));
            visitaAlbero(node, item.getDescendants());
            continue;
        }
        node.addTextItem(item.getDescription());
        node.setWidget(new ItemTree(item));
        visitaAlbero(node, item.getDescendants());
    }
}



/**
 * Inner class che gestisce il widget principale
 * del treeitem 
 * 
 * @author Giuseppe Pedullà
 *
 */
public class ItemTree extends Widget implements Serializable, IsWidget {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5347332077472260376L;

    private Long id;

    private String description;

    private Integer level;

    public ItemTree(Categoria categoria) {
        this.id = categoria.getId();
        this.description = categoria.getDescription();
        this.level = categoria.getLevel();
    }
    public String getDescription() {
        String valueID = "";
        if(id < 10) {
            valueID = "00" + id;
        } else if(id < 100) {
            valueID = "0" + id;
        } else {
            valueID = "" + id;
        }
        return valueID + " - " + description;
    }

    //GETTERS
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public Integer getLevel() {
        return level;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return description;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your `ItemTree` class. It extends Widget but does not set any element for that widget. At least it lacks `asWidget` method. It could be for example like this:

```
@Override
public Widget asWidget() {
    return new Label(getDescription());
}
```

And you could use it like this:

```
firstLevel.setWidget(itemTree.asWidget());
```

---

The easier method is to extend `Composite` instead of `Widget`. You would only need to call `initWidget` method in the constructor:

```
public class ItemTree extends Composite implements Serializable, IsWidget {

    ...

    public ItemTree(Categoria categoria) {
        this.id = categoria.getId();
        this.description = categoria.getDescription();
        this.level = categoria.getLevel();
        initWidget(new Label(getDescription()));    // <- !!!
    }

    ...
}
```

You can initWidget with whatever `Widget` you want - `Label` is the simplest working example - I have successfully tested it.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try soon. I would know what is the point of extending widget if it don't is enough.

Comment: I would like to ask you another thing: if I add an clickListener to the nodes, could I use the information of the Object that extends Composite on server side? Thanks.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Please, post another question(s) and we'll try to answer them.