# Use a wrapper for getting hide information on gwt TreeItem

Tags: java, gwt, tree

I need for knowing how can set my own object to a gwt TreeItem.

I need to see a string but at the same time I must have some other information about that specific TreeItem.

Thank to everyone.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40320966/set-widget-to-treeitem-on-gwt?rq=1

Comment: I can't found any documentation for that. Must I implement some specifics method? How? Because if I implement the "asWidget" method I must return a widget but all of widgets are useless for me. I need implement my own object but I still don't understand how set correctly that to treeitem.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend `TreeItem` and add some properties to it, for example:

```
public class MyTreeItemWidget extends TreeItem {

    private int hiddenValue;

    public MyTreeItemWidget(String text, int hiddenValue) {
        setText(text);
        this.hiddenValue = hiddenValue;
    }

    public int getHiddenValue() {
        return hiddenValue;
    }
}
```

Then you can get the TreeItem, for example `tree.getSelectedItem()`. To get the additional properties you need to cast it to `MyTreeItemWidget`. For example:

```
((MyTreeItemWidget) tree.getSelectedItem()).getHiddenValue()
```

Here is simple example code:

```
TreeItem root = new TreeItem();
root.setText("root");

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    MyTreeItemWidget item = new MyTreeItemWidget("Node " + Integer.toString(i), i);
    root.addItem(item);
}

final Tree tree = new Tree();
tree.addSelectionHandler(new SelectionHandler<TreeItem>() {
    @Override
    public void onSelection(SelectionEvent<TreeItem> event) {
        Window.alert("Selected value is " + Integer.toString(((MyTreeItemWidget) event.getSelectedItem()).getHiddenValue()));
        // -- or --
        Window.alert("Selected value is " + Integer.toString(((MyTreeItemWidget) tree.getSelectedItem()).getHiddenValue()));
    }
});

tree.addItem(root);
root.setState(true);
```

In `SelectionHandler` you can get the selected `TreeItem` from the event or from the tree.

Comment: I don't know why I didn't think about previous. Thank you. I'll try soon

Comment: Sorry but it doesn't work...I think that the cast doesn't work.

Comment: When I click over an node of my tree don't appear any alert window. If I catch an exception there are some stack trace element.

Comment: For example I see there are some errors talking about an Unknown object. For example: Unknown.dynamicCast(...)